# How do I manually sync a Mesibo profile with latest changes from server if that user published its data with LAZY mode?

Tags: mesibo

I made a page where users can update their names and status just like WhatsApp & Telegram.

These changes are published using LAZY mode since I don't want to update every user using the app right away. I just want to fetch it manually when necessary (for example when the user open the chat view with that user). (https://mesibo.com/documentation/api/real-time-api/profiles/#profile-publishing-mode)

The problem is: how can I fetch the updated profile of other users?

Whenever I get the profiles with `Mesibo.getProfile("address")` the data is still not updated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> since I don't want to update every user using the app right away.

Even if you use real-time mode, updates don't go to every user but only those users who have subscribed to it.

https://mesibo.com/documentation/api/real-time-api/profiles/#subscribing-to-a-profile

In lazy mode, it may be updated along with other profiles or when the message is received from the users. Before that, `getProfile` may not return the latest profile.

If you are starting with mesibo, recommend using real-time mode and optimizing later using the lazy mode